# segmentation fault in C linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list, swap

I have written a code in C about swapping adjacent nodes in a linked list, but the code is not running in VSCode due to a segmentation fault. I don't know what's causing it and the code is giving correct output when run on online compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void insert_end(node **head, int d)
{
    node *new_node = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node)), *temp;
    new_node->val = d;
    if (*head == NULL)
        *head = new_node;
    else
    {
        temp = *head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) //segmentation fault
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = new_node;
        new_node->next = NULL;
    }
}

node *swap(node **head)
{
    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->next = *head;
    node *start = (*head)->next;
    while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->next != NULL)
    {
        node *ptr1 = temp->next;
        node *ptr2 = temp->next->next;
        temp->next = ptr2;
        ptr1->next = ptr2->next;
        ptr2->next = ptr1;
        temp = ptr1;
    }

    return start;
}

void disp(node *head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", head->val);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    node *head = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        insert_end(&head, arr[i]);
    }

    node *ptr = swap(&head);
    disp(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Does the code run without a problem anywhere else? I ask because you seem to stress that the problem occurs in VSCode.

Comment: `new_node->val=d;` in `insert_end()` saves the data, but the `next` pointer is uninitialised... Not good when it's the last pointer in the list... (PS: In C, we do not cast the return value from `malloc()`.)

Comment: @Fe2O3 I think you mean _Not good when it's the **first** pointer in the list..._

Comment: @DavidRanieri When the last _is_ the first... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 yeah... :) OP: Use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to initialize all members to `NULL` and you are done.

Comment: Whithout having looked into any details: `->next->next` smells.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't see any problem there (there is a `->next!=NULL` before testing `->next->next`)

Comment: using calloc instead of malloc fixed it :) but I don't understand why using malloc caused the error

Comment: @AnkitGupta because (as pointed out by Fe203) you don't set `new_node->next` to `NULL` when `*head` is `NULL`, in consequence you read garbage in `while(temp->next!=NULL)` adding the second node.

Answer (score 2):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The function `insert_end` can invoke undefined behavior.

First of all it does not check whether a new node was allocated successfully.
Secondly if `*head` is equal to `NULL` then the data member `next` of the new node stays uninitialized

```
if (*head == NULL)
    *head = new_node;
```

This is the reason that this while loop

```
    while (temp->next != NULL) //segmentation fault
        temp = temp->next;
```

produces the segmentaton fault.

Pay attention to that it is inefficient to add new nodes to the tail of a singly-linked list. It would be better in that case to define a two-sided singly-linked list.

The return type `node *` of the function `swap` is confusing. As the function accepts the pointer to the head node by reference through a pointer to it then it will be logically correct to assume that after the calling the function the pointer to the head node will be updated correctly within the function.

But the main problem is allocating additional node within the function

```
node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

that results in a memory leak. The function shall not allocate any node.

And this statement

```
node *start = (*head)->next;
```

can invoke undefined behavior for an empty list. You need to check whether *head is equal to `NULL` or not.

Also you should split the function into two functions. This will make your code more clear and readable. The main function will traverse the list and other will swap two adjacent nodes.

Also your code will be more readable if instead of the shortened name `disp`  there will be used full name `display`. And at least the function parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const` because within the function the passed list is not being changed.

```
void disp(const node *head);
```

And you need one more function that will free all the allocated memory of the list when it is not required any more.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the mentioned functions can be declared and defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int insert_end( node **head, int val )
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( *new_node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if (success)
    {
        new_node->val  = val;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        while( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

FILE *display( const node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next)
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->val );
    }

    fputs( "null", fp );

    return fp;
}

void swap_adjacent_nodes( node **head )
{
    node *current = *head;
    *head = ( *head )->next;

    current->next = ( *head )->next;
    ( *head )->next = current;
}

void swap_node_pairs( node **head )
{
    for ( ; *head && ( *head )->next; head = &( *head )->next->next )
    {
        swap_adjacent_nodes( head );
    }
}

void clear( node **head )
{
    while( *head )
    {
        node *current = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( current );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    node *head = NULL;

    insert_end( &head, 1 );

    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    swap_node_pairs( &head );
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    putchar( '\n' );

    insert_end( &head, 2 );

    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    swap_node_pairs( &head );
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    putchar( '\n' );

    insert_end( &head, 3 );

    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    swap_node_pairs( &head );
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    putchar( '\n' );

    insert_end( &head, 4 );

    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    swap_node_pairs( &head );
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );

    putchar( '\n' );

    free( head );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> null
1 -> null

1 -> 2 -> null
2 -> 1 -> null

2 -> 1 -> 3 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> null
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- the prototype for `main` without arguments should be:

  ```
  int main(void)
  ```
- in function `insert_end()`, you do not initialize `temp->next` when allocating the first node of the list.  `malloc()` does not initialize the memory block, so it is unpredictable what `temp->next` may contain after allocation.  This causes the test `while (temp->next)` to have undefined behavior in the second iteration of the `while` loop when inserting the next item. Depending on circumstances, `temp` may be a null pointer and the problem does not occur (as on the online compiler) or `temp` may contain an invalid pointer causing the segmentation fault you observe on your system.

  Always initialize `temp->next` to `NULL`, and also check for potential allocation failure.

  ```
  void insert_end(node **head, int d) {
      node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
      if (new_node != NULL) {
          new_node->val = d;
          new_node->temp = NULL;
          if (*head == NULL) {
              *head = new_node;
          } else {
              node *temp = *head;
              while (temp->next != NULL)
                  temp = temp->next;
              temp->next = new_node;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- it is quite obscure what the `node *swap(node **head)` function is supposed to achieve.  The intent seems to be to swap pairs of nodes.  In any case, allocating a new `node` is not required and as coded, this node is not freed and may be lost.  Also unclear why `swap` should return a `node *` where it should update the `head` pointer anyway.

  Here is a modified version that returns the updated head node.

  ```
  node *swap(node **head) {
      node *first, *second;
      node **pp = head;
      while ((first = *pp) != NULL && (second = first->next) != NULL) {
          first->next = second->next;
          second->next = first;
          *pp = second;
          pp = &first->next;
      }
      return *head;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your `insert_end` function where you find the segmentation fault occurring.

> ```
> void insert_end(node **head, int d)
> {
>     node *new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)), *temp;
>     new_node->val = d;
>     if (*head == NULL)
>         *head = new_node;
>     else
>     {
>         temp = *head;
>         while (temp->next != NULL) //segmentation fault
>             temp = temp->next;
>         temp->next = new_node;
>         new_node->next = NULL;
>     }
> }
> ```

- You allocate memory for a `node` with `malloc` (you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` in C, unlike C++).
- You initialize `val`.
- You do *not* initialize `next`. This cannot be assumed to be `NULL`.

If it is not `NULL`, then your loop assigns some random address to `temp`, and `temp->next` dereferences that random address. Undefined behavior ensues, but a segmentation fault is likely, which is what you've encountered.

To remedy this, as per comments, you have two options:

- Allocate with `calloc` which initializes all of the memory to `0`.
- Explicitly initialize `new_node->next` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Compile with warnings and debug symbols:

```
$ gcc tt.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g
tt.c:53:6: error: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Werror=main]
   53 | void main()
      |      ^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Step 2 and 3: Fix that, and run with [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html):

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
==5607== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5607== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5607== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5607== Command: ./a.out --leak-check=full
==5607== 
==5607== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5607==    at 0x1091F0: insert_end (tt.c:19)
==5607==    by 0x10935B: main (tt.c:61)
==5607==
```

Step 4: There seems to be an issue with an uninitialized variable in line 19 (the one you marked). Don't do that. Initialize your variables.

Step 5: Also, you leak memory. But probably you just were not at that point yet.

---

A little more insights can be obtained by static code analysis tools, like [clang-tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/):

```
$ clang-tidy tt.c
Error while trying to load a compilation database:
Could not auto-detect compilation database for file "tt.c"
No compilation database found in /home/moooeeeep or any parent directory
fixed-compilation-database: Error while opening fixed database: No such file or directory
json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: No such file or directory
Running without flags.
3 warnings generated.
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:19:27: warning: The left operand of '!=' is a garbage value [clang-analyzer-core.UndefinedBinaryOperatorResult]
        while (temp->next != NULL) //segmentation fault
                          ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:59:5: note: Loop condition is true.  Entering loop body
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:61:9: note: Calling 'insert_end'
        insert_end(&head, arr[i]);
        ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:12:29: note: Uninitialized value stored to field 'next'
    node *new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)), *temp;
                            ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:14:5: note: Taking true branch
    if (*head == NULL)
    ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:61:9: note: Returning from 'insert_end'
        insert_end(&head, arr[i]);
        ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:59:5: note: Loop condition is true.  Entering loop body
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:61:9: note: Calling 'insert_end'
        insert_end(&head, arr[i]);
        ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:14:5: note: Taking false branch
    if (*head == NULL)
    ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:19:27: note: The left operand of '!=' is a garbage value
        while (temp->next != NULL) //segmentation fault
                          ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:41:12: warning: Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'temp' [clang-analyzer-unix.Malloc]
    return start;
           ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:28:25: note: Memory is allocated
    node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                        ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:31:18: note: Field 'next' is not equal to NULL
    while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->next != NULL)
                 ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:31:12: note: Left side of '&&' is true
    while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->next != NULL)
           ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:31:34: note: Assuming field 'next' is equal to NULL
    while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->next != NULL)
                                 ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:31:5: note: Loop condition is false. Execution continues on line 41
    while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->next != NULL)
    ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:41:12: note: Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'temp'
    return start;
           ^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:53:1: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [clang-diagnostic-main-return-type]
void main()
^
/home/moooeeeep/tt.c:53:1: note: change return type to 'int'
void main()
^~~~
int
```

Just address any issue one by one, until you fixed all the warnings.

Comment: That's fine if the platform is one supported by valgrind, but we don't have that information.

Comment: @JeremyP Not a problem for short snippets like this one: https://www.onworks.net/programs/valgrind-online